Making audio signals imitate USB flash drives
If there is a USB port designed for USB flash drives that plays the audio files in that drive when it is connected --such as the ones commonly found in cars-- is there any practical way to turn an audio signal and via a male USB connector make it so somehow the audio player plays the audio? If yes what is it?
My original idea was to use an audio card but I'm not sure if that will work.
Thanks.

Can be done (basically it would need to present a USB mass storage device containing a big WAV file, and then simply return ADC data when the data areas from the WAV are being read), but I'd expect it to be flaky (because the head unit might want to read ahead in the "file"), so probably no one turned into a product.

This is a pretty general question but basically you need some kind of microcontroller with a) a USB interface for mass storage, and b) some form of audio out.  I suggest you search for "arduino usb host" for the first, and "arduino audio shield" for the second.  How you decide which files to play is up to the software you write.  If you can use SD card instead of USB it's a lot easier, but it seems important to your project that it's USB.

Bluetooth is a much better option if the device supports it
